# change xml to json in restful webservice webmessageFormat

Tags: rest

i have a restful webservice with a response of xml. now i want it to be json so i edited the code and changed it to

`ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`

Yet when i try and load it out the format is still xml. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Fiddler
[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

And put this data on **Request headers** under Composer tab

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Sample preview:

[image: Preview]

Comment: i get a 504 error with this in the textview. [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.  What does this error mean? i tried another service i made with lesser data and it works perfectly.

Comment: Run your project, and open a web browser, then enter the address of your service like this, http://localhost:8525/Substitute/UploadApprovals, then you will see the complete error message.

Comment: Okay, i did it but it returns the content of the data. not even parse or formatted as xml nor json. when i open it on ie it doesn't load. But if reverted to WebMessageFormat.Xml it works on IE. UPDATE

on Firefox it is returned as Xml i used the console of firebug to check whats the response and it is in Xml.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the "accept" header. If you compose a request in fiddler and remove text/html from that header or put "application/json" in front of it, the server will start returning data in json format.